# android: load List from Room using CompletableFuture?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-room, completable-future

Since AsyncTask() method is deprecated, I am trying to replace it.  Previously AsyncTask() was used to load CardViews into a RecyclerView list from a Room database.  I am trying to use CompletableFuture() as a replacement but the list does not load.  The Dao method for "List getAllCards()" is giving an error message in Android Studio "Return value of the method is never used" so it sounds like the list is never obtained from the the database.  The Repository gets the List method from the ViewModel and the ViewModel gets the List method call in the MainActivity.

I also want to avoid "ExecutorService.submit(() - > cardDao()).get()" to load the list, since it is blocking.  I show below the ExecutorService submit(() method that was working fine, for reference.

What am I missing here since the list is not loading?

```
Repository

public List<Card> getAllCards() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            List<Card> loadAllCards = new ArrayList<>();
            cardDao.getAllCards();
            return loadAllCards;
        }).thenAcceptAsync(loadAllCards -> getAllCards());
    }
    return null;
}

Dao

@Dao
public interface QuickcardDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cards ORDER BY Sortorder DESC")
    List<Card> getAllCards();
}
```

Here is the AsyncTask() in the Repository that I am trying to replace:

```
public CardRepository(Application application) {
    CardRoomDatabase db = CardRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    cardDao = db.cardDao();
}

public List<Card> getAllCards() {
    try {
        return new AllCardsAsyncTask(cardDao).execute().get();
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

// AsyncTask for reading an existing CardViews from the Room database.
private static class AllCardsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Card>> {

    private CardDao cardDao;

    AllCardsAsyncTask(CardDao dao) {
        cardDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Card> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        return cardDao.getAllCards();
    }
}
```

Here is the submit(() method in the Repository that I am trying to replace:

```
public List<Card> getAllCards() {

    List<Card> newAllCards = null;
    try {
        newAllCards = CardRoomDatabase.databaseExecutor.submit(() -> cardDao.getAllCards()).get();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newAllCards;
}
```

// End

Comment: There’s a fundamental problem even in your old code. You’re creating an async task, but immediately waiting for its result, so it’s like not being asynchronous at all. You are still blocking the caller’s thread. You have to change the logic to “spawn an async task”, “tell what to do when it’s done”. You can’t have an asynchronous operation within a method that must return a result to its caller.

Comment: @Holger Understood.  So doesn't CompletableFuture help in that regard because it will only deliver the result when finished if loading the List to the UI takes places with thenApply Async()?  And that way the issue of returning an empty List is avoided (you mention here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43489281/return-value-directly-from-completablefuture-thenaccept/43514248#43514248)?

Comment: The issue of that other question does not affect you. That was about truly returning the list early while still adding elements to it in another thread. Your question is about a single call to `cardDao.getAllCards()` that does return a fully populated list already (I hope so). That’s why you *can’t* return early with a result. You can only wait for the result (blocking the caller thread) or return without a result (but with a future if you wish) and achieve asynchronous behavior by telling what to do when the result is available.

Comment: Like `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(cardDao::getAllCards) .thenApply(result -> someMethod(result))`. Mind that most UI frameworks require UI modifications to happen in a dedicated UI thread. With AWT/Swing, you’d have to use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(cardDao::getAllCards) .thenApplyAsync(result -> someMethod(result), EventQueue::invokeLater)` to enforce the result consumption in the event dispatch thread. I suppose, Android has a similar construct.

Comment: I could provide you with fully asynchronous code using either RxJava or KotlinCoroutines, if that suits you.

Comment: @Rinat Diushenov Thanks for the offer but I have zero experience with either.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that you don't want to use neither `RxJava` or `coroutines` and i'm not familiar with `CompletableFuture` i wanna suggest you the easiest way to fetch data from database without blocking `UI thread` - using `LiveData`. `LiveData` performs fetch operation on a sepfrate thread by default and then notifies all the observers.

**Here are necessary steps:**

0. Add this dependency to gradle

   `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.3.1"`
1. Get rid of all code related with Asynctask or CompletableFuture

---

2. Add method as follows to your `@Dao` annotated class

   ```
    @Dao
    public interface QuickcardDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cards ORDER BY Sortorder DESC")
    LiveData<List<Card>> getAllCards();}
   ```

---

2. Add method to your Repo as follows

   ```
   public LiveData<List<Card>> getAllCards() {
           return cardDao.getAllCards();   
        }
   ```

---

3. Add method to your ViewModel as follows:

   `public LiveData<List<Card>> getAllCardsLive{ return repo.getAllCards(); }`

---

4. Observe `LiveData` in your Activity

   ```
   `viewModel.getAllCardsLive().observe(getViewLifeycleOwner(), cards ->{
        // submit obtained cards lit to your adapter
    }`
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation on LiveData.  I would use, however I have hundreds of existing filtered and sorted sublists lists in the project that depend on List<>.  Changing it to LiveData<List<>> would require a massive upgrade to the project so that all the filtreed and sorted lists also return LiveData and way too many additional coding hours.  That's why I was looking to something like CompletableFuture for the single getAllCards() method.

Comment: No other credible answers were provided so I awarded your answer the +150, cheers.